# Google Play Services: how to handle peers network disconnection?

Tags: android, google-play-services

In my multiplayer game i have 2 opponents. How can 1 peer be notified when the other one have network problem/disconnection? I was expecting that either `onPeerLeft` or `onPeersDisconnected` where fired, but nothing!

Actually I'm going to implement some kind of ping mechanism so that if one peer does not receive the ping message within a specified time I can throw something to the user (A dialog specifying that opponent disconnected.)

As alternative, is there a callback to listen to when this kind of problem appens?

On the disconnected peer I'm using the `onRealTimeMessageSent` callback  to detect if the peer cannot send data, as follow:

```java
@Override
public void onRealTimeMessageSent(int statusCode, int token, String arg2) {
    //f the peer can't send data 
    if (statusCode == GamesClient.STATUS_REAL_TIME_MESSAGE_SEND_FAILED) {
        //here I show an error dialog and move out of game
    }
}
```

On the other peer, no other callbacks are raised (such as `onPeerLeft` or `onPeersDisconnected`)

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ok, finally I opted for a ping-pong mechanism with a `Timer` sheduling a `Timertask` every 5 seconds in the `onRoomConnected` callback. Then I check the last received ping time before sending the new message, if elapsed time is greater then a ping time, then I'm able to throw the the proper error message. Any other suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might not be calling setRoomStatusUpdateListener(RoomStatusUpdateListener) before calling builder.build()

Edit: where builder is your RoomConfig.Builder

Comment: Yes, i'm setting the listener both on an invitation received and on activity result from the select player intent before calling `build()`. `onPeerLeft` and other overridden methods are called if network connection is ok!. But this is not the case. With a ping exchange I can monitor if i'm sending and receiving data correctly within a time range.

Comment: onPeerDisconnected should be getting called if the other player is forcibly disconnected from the server, onPeerLeft will only get called if it was the player's intention to quit.  You might try putting a Toast on each of the interface methods so you can see when they're called.

Answer (score 0):

The remote peer will not get any messages to indicate the dropped connection. This is as designed (so temporary loss of signal can be handled).

This is confirmed by a Google representative here:

https://github.com/playgameservices/cpp-android-basic-samples/issues/53

I've implemented a ping based timeout.